# How to request both displayname and location under single GetLeaderboardRequest on PLAYFAB

Tags: unity-game-engine, playfab

when I request "GetLeaderboardRequest" as shown below. It returns display name as null. when request without "PlayerProfileViewConstraints" I can read the display name or when request only "PlayerProfileViewConstraints" I can read the country code. However I cant get both displayname and location together.

what is wrong with the code and how can I fix it? Thanks...

````
 public void GetLeaderboard() // world best 
 {
     var request = new GetLeaderboardRequest
     {
         StatisticName = "TotalCountPlayFab",
         StartPosition = 0,
         MaxResultsCount = 20,
 
         ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints
         {
             ShowLocations = true
         }
     };
     PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(request, OnLeaderboardGet, OnError);
 }```
````